# Add variable value to a $ selector

Tags: jquery

I have a FORM which has dynamic input IDs in it. Its very simple e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" id="name2013" value="somevalue">
<input type="hidden" id="house2013" value="somevalue">
```

'2013' is the bit that's added to every ID. It could be 2010, 2012, or 2056 it doesn't matter but it makes it unique. This unique number is stored in a variable e.g. `var currentyear`

In JQuery I need to get the value of this ID and set it to a different element. e.g.

```
$("#MyDiv #LatestName").val($('#name'+currentyear).attr("id");
```

Basically.... `currentyear` is not being appended to `#name` so that JQuery gets the value of `#name2013` and sets it as the value of `#LatestName` (which is a hidden input field)

How do I get the `currentyear` variable to append as part of the selector?

Comment: You're missing your closing `"` for your `type` attribute

Comment: on a side note.. why do you need to use `attr`? Use `.val('name'+currentyear)`

Comment: You also have a syntax error..  you're missing a closing paren.. the `val()` function isn't closed.

Comment: @Krishna don't know. im new to Jquery, just trying to figure it out as I go along!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to be working for me.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/7tbrM/)

```
var currentYear = 2013;
$('#myID').val( $('#name' + currentYear).attr('id') );
```

Looks like you had a minor syntax error at the end, missing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Like this `:)` **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/zbyfZ/ i.e. extract number out of `id`.

`extractedString = $(this).prop('id').replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );`

**correct html**

```
<input type="hidden" id="name2013" value="somevalue"/>
<input type="hidden" id="house2013" value="somevalue"/>
```